# Fiber product of covering spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $p : E → B$ and $p' : E' → B$ be two covering spaces. Show that the fiber product $E \times_B E'$ is a covering of $B$.

So I know the categorical definition of fiber product. And I think in this case the product induces two projection maps $\pi:E_1 \times_B E_2\rightarrow E_1$ and $\pi':E_1 \times_B E_2\rightarrow E_2$ such that $p_1\circ \pi=p_2\circ \pi'$. But I don't really know how to proceed. My feeling is that we can somehow use the categorical language to prove this, without resorting to the basic definition of a covering space, but I'm not sure how. Any hint is appreciated!

Hi all, I've drafted the proof and decided to post it here so you people can help to judge if it's okay. Your help is appreciated! (Sorry that the proof is very verbose, but I just want to make sure I understand how to juggle with the definitions)

Note that $E \times_B E'$ also has a natural map $q$ to $B$, sending $(e,e')$ to $p(e) = p'(e')$. We want to show that $q: E\times_B E'\rightarrow B$ is a covering space. For any $b\in B$, since $p : E \to B$ and $p' : E' \to B$ are covering spaces, there exists open neighborhoods $U_B$ and $U_B'$ of $b$ such that $p^{-1}(U_B)\overset{h}{\cong} U_B \times \Gamma$ and $p'^{-1}(U_B') \overset{h'}{\cong} U_B' \times \Gamma'$. Take $U=U_B\cap U_B'$ then $p^{-1}(U)\cong U \times \Gamma$ and $p'^{-1}(U)\cong U \times \Gamma'$. We claim that $q^{-1}(U)\overset{g}{\cong} U\times(\Gamma \times \Gamma')$, where we define $g(e,e')=(p(e),(p_2\circ h(e), p_2\circ h'(e')))$ and $p_2$ is the projection of product onto the second coordinate.

Given any $(e_1,e_1'),(e_2,e_2')\in q^{-1}(U)$, then by definition of $q$, we have $e_1,e_2\in p^{-1}(U)$ and $e_1',e_2'\in p'^{-1}(U)$. If $g(e_1,e_1')=g(e_2,e_2')$ by construction of $g$, we have $p(e_1)=p(e_2)$, $p'(e_1')=p'(e_2')$ $p_2\circ h(e_1)=p_2\circ h(e_2)$, and $p_2\circ h'(e_1'))=p_2\circ h'(e_2'))$, which together implies that $e_1=e_2$ and $e_1'=e_2'$ so $g$ is injective. We observe that $g$ is also surjective because $h$ and $h'$ are surjective, i.e., given $(b^*,(m,n))\in U\times(\Gamma \times \Gamma')$, we can let $e=h^{-1}(b^*,m)$ and $e'=h'^{-1}(b^*,n)$, then $g(e,e')=(b^*,(m,n))$. Thus, $g$ is a bijection.

The continuity of $g$ follows from composing continuous functions $p,p_2,h$ and $h'$ gives continuous function. For $g^{-1}$, we can explicitly construct it by defining $g^{-1}(b^*,(m,n))=(h^{-1}(b^*,m), h'^{-1}(b^*,n))$. It's straightforward to verify this is indeed the inverse of $g$. Again, since $h,h'$ are homeomorphisms, $g^{-1}$ is a composition of continuous functions and therefore continuous.

Thus, we had obtained the desired homeomorphism $g$. Since $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ are discrete, $\Gamma\times \Gamma'$ is also discrete. Since $p$ and $p'$ are covering maps, $q$ is obviously surjective. Finally, we will show that $q$ is continuous. Given any open set $U\in B$, it's evenly covered by $p$ and $p'$ so $p^{-1}(U)\times p'^{-1}(U)$ is a collection of open sets in $E\times E'$. Because $E\times_B E'$ has topology induced by inclusion in $E\times E$, $q^{-1}(U)\subset p^{-1}(U)\times p'^{-1}(U)$ is open in $E\times_B E'$ so $q$ is indeed continuous.

Therefore, we conclude that $q:E\times_B E'\rightarrow B$ is indeed a covering space.

Comment: I think that the best strategy is to embrace the basic definition of a covering space, and to translate the categorical definition of fiber product into that language.

Comment: @LeeMosher okay...I just thought there will be some categorical nice structures to use. I will go back and use the basic definition now...

Comment: In seems like any categorical proof essentially boils down to the existence of products in the category of covering spaces over $B$ (which, a priori, need not exist). Of course, to determine this, *some* definition a covering space must be used, since without it you can't really say anything about what is and is not in the category.

Comment: @Kajelad Okay, thank you for the comment! We had a proposition that fundamental group of product space is product of fundamental groups, and that one had a nice categorical approach, so naturally I was thinking like that again, though turns out I’m wrong haha.

Comment: @Kajelad : well if you really want to play the categorical advocate (although all in all I agree with you !) the usual classification theorem shows that (if $B$ is nice enough) the category of covering spaces is equivalent to the category of $\Pi_1(B)$-sets, which clearly has products. Of course this isn't a "good" proof here (not full generality, and requires much more heavy machinery than what is needed)

Comment: Okay...people, I almost got the proof. I will post it soon in an edit to the question. Can you help to check its validity?

Comment: @Macrophage It would be best if you answered your own question — this way you could feedback through voting as well as comments directly tied to your answer — as opposed to having your attempt in the body of the question.

Comment: Continuity of $q$ is trivial because $q = p \circ \pi = p' \circ  \pi'$.